# Insert characters into existing cells

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update a group of cells by inserting the same two characters into all of them, but I'm just drawing a blank on how to do this.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

**Old Cells**
HI.1 
HI.2
HII.1

**New Cells**
H08I.1
H08I.2
H08II.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE Cells SET Cell = LEFT(Cell, 1) + '08' + SUBSTRING(Cell, 1, LEN(Cell)-1)
```

Comment: This assumes you want to insert after the first character (but doesn't assume it's an "H").

Comment: If it IS always an "H", and the only "H" in the cell, then @Tony Andrews's answer is good.

Answer (score 2):

If all your cells look like that:

```
update cells
set cell = Replace(cell,'H','H08');
```

(But note that Replace doesn't care where the 'H' appears).

Note: I am assumign we are talking about SQL and tables here - maybe a "cell" is something else?

Comment: By cells I meant cells within a table.  Although I didn't specify, there are multiple H's, so Michael's answer will work better for my needs.  Thanks for the response.